# Optimal Chunk Size to Send File in Python?

Tags: python, sockets

I'm actually using python's (2.7) ftplib to send files to an FTP server, but under the hood it uses socket.sendall. The function of interest is below:

```
def storbinary(self, cmd, fp, blocksize=8192, callback=None, rest=None):
    """Store a file in binary mode.  A new port is created for you.

    Args:
      cmd: A STOR command.
      fp: A file-like object with a read(num_bytes) method.
      blocksize: The maximum data size to read from fp and send over
                 the connection at once.  [default: 8192]
      callback: An optional single parameter callable that is called on
                on each block of data after it is sent.  [default: None]
      rest: Passed to transfercmd().  [default: None]

    Returns:
      The response code.
    """
    self.voidcmd('TYPE I')
    conn = self.transfercmd(cmd, rest)
    while 1:
        buf = fp.read(blocksize)
        if not buf: break
        conn.sendall(buf)
        if callback: callback(buf)

    conn.close()
    return self.voidresp()
```

I am trying to choose the optimal block size, or at least understand the things affecting it. The code is currently running on a local gigabit network, with a 0.2ms ping time to the FTP server (yes, 0.2ms, not 0.2s), on Ubuntu kernel 3.2. I have a decent understanding of TCP window scaling and  send/receive/congestion windows. I am sending 2GB files across this network and have found, in practice, that the transfer speed increases with block size, up to 533Mb/s using 256KB block size. For reference, a block size of 64KB gives around 330Mb/s.

I'm not complaining about those speeds by any means, but want to understand why 256KB block size is optimal. Everything I have found so far indicates that ~64KB is the larges chunk size needed. I have timed the sub components of the storebinary function to ensure that the total time to send the file actually decrease as chunk size increases up to 256KB (as opposed to time spent reading the file).

My code to transfer these 2GB files will eventually be run on many networks (though same OS, kernel, python version). I am worried about 256KB being sub optimal on other networks and I am curious to why 256KB block size gives the fastest transfer speed. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: For those of you concerned with how I timed the actual socket.sendall call, independently, here is the modified version of the function I used to time this. Going from 64KB chunks to 256KB chunks brought read time from ~19s to ~14s and send time from ~18s to ~10s.

```
def storbinary(self, cmd, fp, blocksize=8192, callback=None, rest=None):
    """Store a file in binary mode.  A new port is created for you.

    Args:
      cmd: A STOR command.
      fp: A file-like object with a read(num_bytes) method.
      blocksize: The maximum data size to read from fp and send over
                 the connection at once.  [default: 8192]
      callback: An optional single parameter callable that is called on
                on each block of data after it is sent.  [default: None]
      rest: Passed to transfercmd().  [default: None]

    Returns:
      The response code.
    """
    self.voidcmd('TYPE I')
    conn = self.transfercmd(cmd, rest)
    totalTime = 0
    totalSendTime = 0
    totalCallbackTime = 0
    while 1:
        startTime = time.time()
        buf = fp.read(blocksize)
        endTime = time.time()
        if not buf: break
        totalTime += (endTime - startTime)
        startTime = time.time()
        conn.sendall(buf)
        endTime = time.time()
        totalSendTime += (endTime - startTime)
        startTime = time.time()
        if callback: callback(buf)
        endTime = time.time()
        totalCallbackTime += (endTime - startTime)

    print 'Total read time was %s'%str(totalTime)
    print 'Total send time was %s'%str(totalSendTime)
    print 'Total callback time was %s'%str(totalCallbackTime)
    conn.close()
    return self.voidresp()
```

Comment: You might want to consider implementing this so that the block size can change dynamically, then you can just use heuristics to pick a good size and you don't have to hard code it.

Comment: Are you reading from a hard drive, as opposed to an SSD?  Your limiting factor is probably the read speed of the hard drive the file is stored on.

Comment: As an experiment, try reading the entire file into memory first.  That will eliminate the possibility of it being a disk bottleneck.

Comment: @JamieCockburn If you noticed in my OP, I mentioned that I timed the actual send portion of that function. The total time spent on socket.sendall does in fact decrease (from ~18s to ~10s for all 2GB) when I use 256KB vs 64KB. The reading is also faster with larger block size, but I'm focusing on the send currently. Something I am considering now is that when I send larger block sizes, the socket.send call returns while some of the data to send is still buffered by the OS. Therefore the OS is sending while my program is reading the next buffer.

Comment: @maxywb I have considered dynamically adjusting the block size, but we are at a point in production where the higher ups don't want to add such a change. It is planned for the next release of the code, but for now we are trying to nail down a decent, constant block size based on network speed and latency only.

Comment: I doubt it's a function of your physical network. The network stack is going to have break up the data into ~1500 byte chunks (9000 bytes if jumbo frames are being used) in order for it to fit into Ethernet packets. It's probably just because Python is slow. Fewer loop iterations in Python, more in the C code that implements sendall() is probably where the better transfer rate is coming from. Hmm... your CPU L2 cache is probably 256KB, that also might be factor.

Comment: @RossRidge I agree, I doubt it has anything to do with the physical network (or even OS TCP stack). I think the main issue is not the application run speed, but just the way this function is written with the sequential read then send. The function cannot start reading the next block until socket.sendall has returned. So the optimal block size here is dependent on how fast the network can empty the OS send buffer, the send buffer size (net.ipv4.tcp_wmem), and read speed. The function would be much faster if the reading were on a different thread, so sending and reading happened simultaneously.

Comment: The OS is probably prefetching blocks ahead of your reads, so there would already be some sending and reading happening simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bits in the ftp are based on datagrams, so they are send in packets of a particular size through a fixed path. To send all data either you need to determine the size of the complete file and then expect the same on the ftp end. The better way is to add an ending Delimiter at the end of the file. So when you loop across the file's content on the ftp end and you find the ending delimiter you must stop expecting more data in the file from the same client. Keep the nominal size of the bits transferred in a single send to be about 1024, which is preferred size due to various reasons(please do find the reasons to that on Google, you will find it easily).